# Javascipt calculator with 2 classes

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have to use this index.js and create Calculator.js that have to do all the maths. Also I have to use lodash ( filter and reduce).

```
    const _ = require('lodash');


const Calculator = require('./Calculator.js')

const item1 = new Calculator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
const item2 = new Calculator([1, 'text', 3, {}])

item1.sum()
item1.subtract()

item2.sum()
item2.subtract()
```

calculator.js

```
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = class Calculator {
  constructor(items=[]){
    this.items = items;
    _.filter(this.items, typeof(number))
  }
  sum(){
    _.reduce(this.items, function(sum, n) {
  return sum + n;
},0)}
  
  subtract(){
    _.reduce(this.items, function(sum, n) {
  return sum - n;
  },0)}
}
```

It should give me result in console but it's just a blank page. I'm sitting on it for like 1h and I just can't find how to fix the code.

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask questions more suited for stackoverflow :) Its not clear what you're asking here, so feel free to edit once you've taken a read over

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: It should give me the sum number in console right? but its just blank

Comment: im using replit.com just started uni

Comment: Where is the code that prints the result? Also for item2 use actual numbers instead of strings and empty dicts to first test it with actual numbers.

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter _.reduce should print it

Comment: After `item2.subtract()` can you do a console.log("test") and see if that prints

Comment: Yup console.log("test") works

Comment: Do `var item1_sum= item1.sum();console.log(item1_sum)` I believe you're not returning the value and then printing it. In the sum function you need to return the value also like `return _.reduce `

Comment: it works now but I have to find a way to filter it

Answer (score 1):

Both `_.reduce()` and `_.filter()` create new arrays that you need to assign or return (see comments). You also need to wrap the method calls with `console.log()` to see the results for the same reasons.

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(items = []) {
    this.items = _.filter(items, _.isNumber) // filter with _.isNumber and assign to this.items
  }
  sum() {
    // return the sum
    return _.reduce(this.items, function(sum, n) {
      return sum + n;
    }, 0)
  }
  subtract() {
    // return the difference
    return _.reduce(this.items, function(sum, n) {
      return sum - n;
    }, 0)
  }
}

const item1 = new Calculator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
const item2 = new Calculator([1, 'text', 3, {}])

// wrap the method calls with console.log to see the results
console.log(item1.sum())
console.log(item1.subtract())

console.log(item2.sum())
console.log(item2.subtract())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```